# Selecting Data from another table SQL Select Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, performance

Here is 2 Tables that are joined by the StaffID

```
Job Table
=========
JobID AssignedTo(StaffID) Created By(StaffID)
1     2                   1
2     3                   2

Staff Table
============
StaffID Name
1       May
2       Bob
3       Mary
```

I need An SQL Statement to get the job details with the corresponding staff name but have problems doing so as i'm unable to differentiate the columns as they are using the same table. The end result should look like this

```
JobID Assigned To  Created By
1     Bob          May
2     Mary         Bob
```

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL? You tagged both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join `Staff` table twice

```
select J.JobId, S1.Name AS AssignedTo, S2.Name AS CreatedBy
from Job J
inner join Staff S1 on S1.StaffID = J.AssignedTo
inner join Staff S2 on S2.StaffID = J.CreatedBy
```

Comment: Man u are 2 sec early just wrote this one `select j.jobid , s1.Name as Assigned_To, s2.Name as Created_By
from Job j
inner join Staff st1 on st1.StaffID = j.AssignedTo
inner join Staff st2 on st2.StaffID = j.CreatedBy`

Comment: Where do i put my other tables that are connected to it? Lets say i have a customer table connected to the job table by CustomerID... It would be like this? SELECT j.jobid,c.name FROM Job j , Customer c ..etc?

Comment: If you want to add more tables connected to `Job`, simply add more joins.

Comment: Thanks! was searching on subqueries and couldn't find the answer. Thanks again for your quick reply!